# Is it possible to fork the current pane in tmux and put it in a new pane?

Tags: bash, tmux, fork

Often I have set up some temporary environment variables/modules and I would like them to persist as I create a split in Tmux. Is it possible to fork the current running program (i.e. bash) and put that into a new split?

Demonstration:

```
Before                 After
+----------+           +-----------+
|          |           |     |     |
|   bash   |           |bash1|bash2|
|          |           |     |     |
+----------+           +-----------+
```

Both `bash1` and `bash2` should be in the same state.

If this is not possible directly with Tmux, what is a good way to emulate this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "fork" and "state". `tmux` allows you to split a pane in two. Do you want them to be the same, i.e. showing the exact same thing (to "clone" a pane)?

Comment: @Kusalananda Fork the process. I don’t want two panes reading from the same buffer, instead I want Tmux to fork the running process resulting with another independent running process branches off from the original one.

Comment: So if `vim` is running with some open files in the main pane, you'd like `vim` to be opened with the same files in the new split pane too? I don't really see how that would be possible.